# Why is the CORS pre-flight OPTIONS call not being made?

Tags: javascript, cors

I have a server running on `localhost:8080`.  I also have a small `jquery` app running on `localhost:3001`.  In that app I have an `ajax` call:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'https://localhost:3001/posts.json',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        data: {
            "post": {
                name: "Blog 1",
                title: "Another blog",
                content: "This is a blogggg"            
            }
        }
```

Because they are running on 2 different ports, I am expecting the `CORS` protocol to set in.  With this being a `POST`, with a the `Content-Type` being set to `application/json`, I would expect an `OPTIONS` call to be made first, but my server is routing it directly to the `POST`.
Here is what happened in the network tab of my dev tools.

[image]

As you can see there is no `OPTIONS` call.  What needs to happen for this to be routed as I am expecting?

Comment: I believe the preflight happens internally in the browser, and that you won't see it as a request in the console, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It should however be visible in the server logs ?

Comment: The result of a Preflight request [may be cached](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#preflight-result-cache-0), so it doesn't have to be sent again until that expires.

Comment: It is visible in the dev tools and I have logging in my server, in which it isn't being hit.  I will check if it is caching.